# Porque el api de word Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll no cuenta la misma cantidad de caracteres que el de word

Tags: c#

Utilizo el api de word Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll y no me cuenta la misma cantidad de caracteres que me cuenta el microsoft word. Algunos de ustedes puede tener una respuesta a esta incognita que llevo varias semanas trabado en esto.

```
  Word.Application App = new Word.Application();
  Word.Document Doc = App.Documents.Open(ruta);   
  int totalP = Doc.Characters.Count;
```

Utilicé la api y el conteo me dio 1 caracter sin embargo con el word me dio 1674 caracteres con espacios.(Quiero aclarar que mi archivo de word contiene cuadros de texto). Aqui esta el archivo https://drive.google.com/open?id=19rbeztGR_3HaRI4B0Re_etU4NVQholnI